# React full image background

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I know this is basic but I'm also a beginner trying to figure out things but it doesn't work out to be good.

How can I make this full image background in my react. I'm making a portfolio for my projects.

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This is my index.css

And I have a component for the image inside my component

```
const background = {
    backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`,
    height: "100%",
    backgroundPosition: "center",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundSize: "cover",
};
```

then I'm calling it here in my react component

```
return (
    <div style={background}>
        <h1> Hello </h1>
    </div>
)
```

But I'm getting this kind of result.
[image]

tried searching different approaches but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use vh and vw to ensure your application fills the whole screen:

```
<div style="height:100vh;width:100vw">TEST</div>
```

In your case:

```
const background = {
    backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`,
    backgroundPosition: "center",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw
};
```

If you just set height to 100% your background just fills the container (body).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this background style for this:

```
const background = {
    backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`,
    height: "100vh",
    backgroundPosition: "center",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundSize: "cover",
};
```

Percents it is relative unit, and it will take 100% of parent size.
Vh (viewport height) it's unit, that based on the devices size, so 100 vh will set element size equal to full-screen height.
About viewport:

https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-viewport-units-vw-vh-wmin-vmax/

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably caused by you'r root element no being heigh enough.

You'll need to add some CSS to let the first element be large enough:

```css
#app {
   height: 100%;
}
```

---

Small example:

```js
const Example = () => {

    const Background = 'https://picsum.photos/200/300';

    const background = {
        backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`,
        height: "100%",
        backgroundPosition: "center",
        backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
        backgroundSize: "cover",
    };

    return (
        <div style={background}>
            <h1> Hello </h1>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    height: 100%;
}

#app {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
height: "100%",
```

with:

```
height: 100vh,
width: 100vw,
```

This is because you want the background to fill the entire [viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp), that is, **the user's visible area of a web page**, and not just the area of the component.